# How to define collapsible hamburger menu in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resolution, hamburger-menu

I've been playing around with my nav bar and menu set up, but can't seem to get the Hamburger menu to trigger when I re-size my browser window.

My attempt below, where I defined the data toggle and set it's target to the main nav bar didn't work when re-sizing the browser.

**Question:**

Does anyone know why the hambuger menu isn't triggering on re-size with this markup?

```
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    //Defined the toggle here, pointing it's data-target to the navBarCollapsable main nav bar.
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBarCollapsable">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBarCollapsable">
      <nav>
        <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a>Selection:</a></li>
          <li>
            <a>Assets <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 6</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="horizontalgap" style="width:10px"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a>Profile:</a></li>
          <li>
            <a>Assets <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabindex="-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 6</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="horizontalgap-md"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: did you paste bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js???

Comment: yes both stylesheet and js references are there. My bootstrap is rendering but the hamburger datatoggle never appears on re-size of browser to small.

Comment: can you please put your code in snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Where did you come up with this DOM structure? It doesn't follow the documentation which is probably why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at this code http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/bKFzD you will see that both his menu types are included in the nav tag so try wrapping both your normal menu and your hamburger menu with `<nav>`

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag should come immediately after  tag. Also make sure that your jquery.js file is loaded before bootstrap.js.